# Advanced Installer - Install or Maintenance

Tags: advanced-installer

I am using **Advanced Installer** and would like to know where do I configure when it needs to take the **Installation** process and when it need to take the **Maintenance** process. I am not sure if it is configurable. If not I would like to know how Windows decides which process to perform. help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to configure that, the packages created by Advanced Installer know exactly when to go to install or maintenance phase, this is controlled by Windows Installer on each machine where you install the package. [Try the simple installation tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html) to see how it works.

Basically, each package has guide, the product code, that is registered on the system by Windows Installer when you run it first and install your app. The second time you launch the same MSI Windows Installer will see the product code is registered as installed and automatically enter maintenance, showing the appropriate dialogs.

If you don't want a package to be enter maintenance phase, i.e. run only the install phase (every time you launch it) just go to Product Details page in your project and untick the option "*Register product with Windows Installer*".

Comment: The problem is that every time I create a new instance of the installer it starts the installation process (even though it is of the same version of the application). Hence I have several instances of the same application in my **Programs & Features** window. What I'm trying to find out is what parameter changes that cause this issue.

Comment: Have you enabled the support for multiple instances from Media page? Or done something that could automatically change the product code when you build the packages?

Comment: The **Multiple Instances** option is disabled but according to the log files the **product code** is different (I read in **Advanced Installer** website that "You must allow the generation of the new product code if you want to allow the automated upgrade of older versions of the product and to prevent the installation of older versions over newer ones. Otherwise, not generating a new Product Code will ensure that only one version of the product can be installed on the computer. Also you must generate a new Product Code for side-by-side installation of different versions to work.")

Comment: The statement you got from the website is correct, for WHEN you generate a new version, let say version 2.0 of your app. But if the version is the same the product code should also remain the same. To test your installers use the "Run" command from AI, this will remove a package with the same version and product code from your machine and allow re-installing it again, during your development.